# How to divide logic between application + jQuery plugin (with $.widget factory)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, widget

I'm just getting started writing plugins with the [jQuery widget factory](http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide).

From the stuff I've read it's not clear where to divide the logic between your application and plugin code.

For example, in writing a slideshow plugin, should the click handlers etc. go inside the plugin, or should the plugin just expose public prev/next methods + events which your application code hooks on to?

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on how the plugin is intended to be used.

A plugin for a very novice user should do all on its own but a plugin directed at webdesigners that might like to make their own GUi for viewing should expose methods.

Answer (score 1):

There's no hard and fast rules around this, it all comes down to the 'scope' of an individual plugin which ultimately is defined by you, the plugin author.

For instance a slideshow plugin is likely to always have next and previous buttons so it makes complete sense to include those in the widget and hook up the events to call the appropriate (public) next and prev methods. On the other hand if your application happend to require the slideshow to scroll when pressing `shift+ctrl+windowslogo+command+fn+1+2+3+e+<+tab` then this isn't very common so it'd be unlikely you'd want to bind to that in the plugin code; but of there's no reason you shouldn't expose an API to allow this to be achieved.